# How to modify an existing SSRS report using report wizard

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here but I've been searching for half an hour to no avail. In Visual Studio, if I right click on Report and select Add new report then I can do things like select the data source, and input a SQL query. If I want to (for example) change the SQL query of an *existing* report, how do I do this? Surely I don't have to delete & recreate the report?

Comment: Just open the existing report and edit the things you need to change?

Comment: @NickyvV "Open" how exactly?

Comment: Double click on it, or select `Add existing item` if the report is not yet in your project/solution.

Comment: If working with a single report, it helps to create a "dummy" project and add the existing report to it. Afterwards you should be able to edit the datasources, datasets and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reopen the wizard that you used to initially create the report (or chart).  It's a one time wizard that generates a report that you have to manually tweak afterward.

The good news is that it shouldn't take too much effort to change simple things on the report you have. There are lots of examples on SO about how to change the query/expressions or anything else you need to modify.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue when I wanted to change my query and add a new field. A workaround is to manually modify the rdl file:

1. Righ click on your report (on the solution explorer)
2. View code
3. Paste your new query within the < CommandText >< /CommandText >
4. Add a new < Field >< /Field > in the list

Comment: Why are you including pictures of text in your answer? These are useless to visually impaired users, as well as those with image servers blocked. Please [edit] your answer to include the relevant text.